# Getting Entry Process Overload with PHP to Dynamically Set Meta Tags

Tags: php, html, hosting

I'm using RapidWeaver to create a blog page at www.chocchoc.club/blog/index.php

Because of how the program works I cannot manually set the meta tags for each page so have tried to do it using some PHP, so that I can set some OG an Twitter Cards meta information. In this case I'm using a function to get the URL and Site Title from the HTML. Here's what I've got so far..

At the very start of the php page:

```
<?php

    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    function getTitle($url){
      $str = file_get_contents($url);
      if(strlen($str)>0){
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
      return $title[1];
        }
      }
?>
```

This should set the variable $url to the URL of the page and set the function getTitle to get the text within the `<title>` tags of the page.

Here's the HTML and PHP I'm using to put this into the document:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo getTitle("$url"); ?>" />
```

Now this works and produces the HTML that I want...

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.chocchoc.club/blog/files/important-news.php" />
<meta property="og:title" content="'We're stockpiling Flakes!' Brits in US aghast at Cadbury's ban | #ChocChoc Blog" />
```

However, I am hosting on Godaddy shared hosting and since implementing this code I've gotten a lot of Service Unavailable errors.

When checking the CPU and concurrent connections page I get this message:

> Your site has been limited within the past 24 hours You have reached
>   entry processes (number of simultaneously running php and cgi scripts,
>   as well as cron jobs and shell sessions) limit 712 times

Here's the entry processes graph for the last 24 hours (I'm writing this in the morning after I was working on site and viewing it so they have dropped off).

http://www.chocchoc.club/images/ep_godaddy.tiff

(Can't post images as this is my first post)

Here's the detail from the log:

http://www.chocchoc.club/images/cpu_connections_usage_details.tiff

Strange is that 15:00 was midnight for me and when I left it alone. But processes kept occurring for a few hours after...

Any ideas if this PHP code could be the culprit?! A friend of mine says that it could be a function not terminated correctly?

Thanks for any help received!

-Neil

Comment: Hi Neil, do you use windows or linux hosting ?

Comment: Linux hosting with cPanel

Comment: Does this function get called often? Or just once or twice?

Comment: I'm not sure - I'm new to PHP - the idea is that the function runs once. It's used twice within the page to set two meta tags like this: <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo getTitle("$url"); ?>" />

Answer (score 0):

**Any ideas if this PHP code could be the culprit?**
*Yes, your code is in an loop*

**Whats causing your problem**

Your function is using `file_get_contents` this function is requesting the content of an file or an webpage and put this in an string. In case of an webpage its taking the html out of this website and runs it like an normal http request.

So you are requesting the same website you are currently on. When you load the website it loads the website again and again. So they are in an loop.

`$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` « loads website over and over.

**An Fix?**

When I understand it correctly the RapidWeaver software does not have the possibility to get the page title with an easy function. When you have access to there core you can change it from there, maybe write an hook/extention that makes it possible.

If you do wanna use the `file_get_contents` way you can do it like this. So only the request from the user is parsed. But be aware that its an 'dirty' way, that can result in memory overloads and DDOS vulnerability

```
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] . "?mode=skip";

function getTitle($url){
  if($_GET['mode'] != 'skip') {
    $str = file_get_contents($url);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
        return $title[1];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm no expert but the Memory Usage on the hosting panel shows moderate usage but nothing near the limit. The issue is with the Entry Processes (i.e. number of simultaneous visitors) - now all the traffic last night was coming from my IP address so when I viewed a page once it was like I was viewing it hundreds of times.

Comment: Hi Neil. Could be that the two things hang together, could be they are not. I found this topic on prowebmasters http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51805/how-to-find-what-is-maxing-out-my-entry-processes hope that can solve your problem.

Comment: Assuming it is the PHP on the page is there anything wrong with the code I've used? If there's nothing wrong with the code I'll give GoDaddy a call to try and trac down the issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi Neil. I took another look after I drink some coffee and found the loop. I updated my question, but a real fix I dont know. I hope this clarify that its indeed in your code..

Comment: Makes sense. Will have to work out a fix. May be easiest to exclude the first few lines of the file that contains the PHP function?

Comment: You requesting the file via the HTTP request so it just reads the HTML. Thats also why its looping. Example: user request foo.com -> your script runs and request foo.com -> foo.com is again requested -> runs your script and request foo.com again. ( so the whole approach of requesting the page your on is not going to work )

Comment: If I put the PHP into its own file and request it from index.php would that sort it? Or as your first answer suggested only retrieve part of the html?

Comment: If you request the index.php (on your own server) you get only the PHP code. So nothing is parsed, there is no title there.. Just retrieve a part does also not work, because you still make the HTTP request. The whole approach with `file_get_contents` is not going to fly..

Comment: Any ideas on how to get just the html code that the browser sees then?

Comment: You can add an parameter so skip the parsing when you are making the request from your php file. But it does not deserve a beauty award..

Comment: Can you think of any other solutions that may get a beauty award?! I'm guessing most CMS systems have a way to call various elements like the title url image-link etc for use in meta tags but unfortunately Rapidweavers blog function does not. So this is kind of a special use case scenario but might be useful for other applications. I can't imagine setting a PHP variable from its selfs page content should be that difficult!

Comment: # start redirecting output to a buffer ob_start();  # execute the other PHP file include('myfile.php');  # grab whatever got output since ob_start() (and stop buffering) $html = ob_get_clean();